# How to create different JSON output for a complex object

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

I would like to generate different Json output for the same complex Java object depending on the use case.

For example check the following code:

```
class Employee {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private EmployeeDetail detail;
    private Department department;
    ...
}

class Department {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    ...
}

class EmployeeDetail {
    private Long id;
    private int salary;
    private Date birthDate;
    ...
}
```

If I convert Employee to Json all of the fields from Employee, EmployeeDetail and Department will be present. And it is good for one use case.

However in the second use case I would like to skip Department details except the id field but keep the complete EmployeeDetail.

I know that I can add something similar `@JsonView(EmployeeView.Basic.class)` to the `id` field in the `Department` class and use Json views. However for cleaner code I would like to solve it inside the Employee class something like this:

```
class Employee {
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @JsonAllFields
    private EmployeeDetail detail;

    @JsonIdOnly
    private Department department;
    ...
}
```

At the moment I use the Jackson library but can switch if required.

Comment: Could you create a 'presentation' class for each type of output you need that accepts the 'root' classes in the constructor (to populate it) but only contains the relevant fields for your JSON output?

Comment: Yes, it can work but I try to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.

@JsonIgnore is used to ignore the logical property used in serialization and deserialization. @JsonIgnore can be used at setter, getter or field. You can use it in the fields in Department class except on ID. There are so many ways to do it. Either you can allow the only getter in serialization etc.

Example:

```
@JsonIgnore(false)
private String id;
```

OR

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "bookName", "bookCategory" })
public class Book {
   @JsonProperty("bookId")
   private String id;

   @JsonProperty("bookName")        
   private String name;

   @JsonProperty("bookCategory")    
   private String category;  

}
```

To know more about it, please refer: https://www.concretepage.com/jackson-api/jackson-jsonignore-jsonignoreproperties-and-jsonignoretype

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a solution using `@JsonFilter`

Now the Employee class looks like this:

```
class Employee {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private EmployeeDetail detail;

    @JsonFilter("departmentFilter")
    private Department department;
    ...
}
```

And the code to generate the limited json looks like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

SimpleFilterProvider filterProvider = new SimpleFilterProvider();
filterProvider.addFilter("departmentFilter", SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept("id"));

mapper.setFilterProvider(filterProvider);
```

One small cons is that now I also need to define the filter to generate the full, detailed json like this:

```
filterProvider.addFilter("departmentFilter", SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAll());
```